# Object kept in memory until Forcing GC

Tags: java, dictionary, garbage-collection, concurrenthashmap

I have got such code:

```
public static class Obj {//Class within class
Long a;

}

private static final Map<String, Obj> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for(long l = 0;l<10000090L;l++)
    {
        Obj o = new Obj();
        o.a = l;
        map.put("asd", o);
        map.remove("asd");
    }
}
```

On my PC i have added this code in a Thread - so i can easily see memory usage. I have started profiling it with Your Kit Java Profiler.

I have added additional arguments to VM: -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing

My result of testing this program:
Before loop Your Kit is showing - User Par Serivce Space 0 bytes, User Par Eden Space 12 mb, Used CMS Old Gen 0 Bytes
After loot Your Kit is showing - User Par Serivce Space 8 KB, User Par Eden Space 38 mb, Used CMS Old Gen 0 Bytes 1,6 mb

Then i forced Garbage Collector, results:
Your Kit is showing - User Par Serivce Space 0 bytes, User Par Eden Space 1,4 mb, Used CMS Old Gen 1,5 mb

So if i read this values correctly, Obj or "asd" is staying in memory until Full Garbage collector. 
Is there any way to make those objects be removed in real time without waiting for Garbage collector to check is every object in program can be accessed?

Comment: I don't see any thread started in this code.

Comment: only chuck norris can force the garbagecollector to clean up! you can only kindly ask it to do so

Comment: 1. The GC runs when Java decides it needs to be run.  2. Java is almost certainly smarter than you at deciding when the GC needs to be run.

Comment: `-XX:+UseTLAB` is the default. The GCs job is to collect garbage, and nothing else collects garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Garbage Collector jumps in whenever it is required and in most of the cases it jumps in at a time which is the most optimized. Manually request GC to trigger using `System.gc()` might not give advantage at all.

Moreover, how do you know if "abj" is staying till full gc. Your eden generation has occupied 38 mb space and 0 mb in old generation. Which in your case with only short lived objects is the expected behavior (And normally small gc's should work unless you insert at a very fast rate and eden filled up quite quickly)

Comment: Do you know how can i run small gc just for tests? Also is there any way to force full GC that isn't stopping the world(i use ConcMarkSweepGC)

Comment: You cannot trigger just small gc or full gc. Call `System.gc` will just request collector to collect. Based on the current state it might or might not choose to do collection. And if it does, only based on current memory utilization it might prefer doing full. IMHO there is no way of doing it... For second part, ConcMarkSweepGC gives the least amount of pauses and there should be very small time where it stops the world. If still unhappy try azul systems JVM. They guarrantee it doesn't stop the wold any time.

Comment: Normally my ConcMarkSweepGC is working fine, only when i am trying to force it, world stops and (concurrent mode interrupted) is logged. I am trying to figure out which objects can be cleaned by small GC and which objects need Full GC in my program

Comment: As I explained that GC is triggered when it is best for program. There are many cases where calling System.gc only worsens the performance. Frankly I do not understand what you are exactly trying to do.

Comment: @user2618929 Only Azul Zing has a fully concurrent collector.

Answer (score 2):

The garbage collector is the only thing that ever removes objects from memory.  You can call `System.gc()` any time you like, which requests for the garbage collector to run sooner, rather than later.  But usually, there's no need to.  The garbage collector will run of its own accord, before your program gets into memory problems.